# Undo in Vim according to time?

Tags: vim

Is there any way (like plug-in) to undo changes in Vim buffer according to time, like undo the changes in the last 30 minutes, or undo changes after 2pm today? I just found `[count]u` is not that useful for some change sequence which is a little long.

Comment: There is now a [dedicated stackexchange site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for vi and vim, next time you might want to post in there ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To go back to a state of some earlier time you can use [`:earlier`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#:earlier), e.g. to go back 30 minutes

```
:earlier 30m
```

`:earlier` takes relative times so to go back to a state at a certain time you would need to do the calculation yourself (but you could wrap that in a custom function).

To explore the undo tree plugins like [Gundo](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim) can be very handy.

Comment: The link to Gundo seems to be broken. Has it gone the way of the dodo?

Comment: @lindhe, looks like they moved to Github. I have updated the link.